# I am trying to do lift state up by using function component, help me to clear that error, trying to share the same input values for both the fields

Tags: reactjs

```
const Nivedhan = () => {            // parent component
const[val,setVal]=useState('')

  function change(e){
   setVal(e.target.value)
  }
 
  return (
       
    <div>
     
      <Nivedhan2 values={change}/>
      <Nivedhan3 values={change}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Nivedhan;  


//============================================================================



function Nivedhan2(props){         // child comp 1
  
  function Handle(e){
    props.values(e.target.value)
  }
  
  return(<div>
    <input type='text' onChange={Handle}></input>
  </div>)

}

//=============================================================================
function Nivedhan3(props){        // child comp 2
  
  function Handles(e){
    props.values(e.target.value)
  }
  
  return(<div>
    <input type='text' onChange={Handles}></input>
  </div>)

}
```

Error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined.. I am getting this error. If I want to type the text in the 1st input field means it should be reflect in the 2nd field box simultaneously by using lift state up method.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you pass down `e.target.value` to `props.values` and , that `change` method tries to access `e.target.value` once again resulting in: `e.target.value.target.value`

Try passing directly to `props.values`:

```
function Nivedhan2(props){         // child comp 1
  
  function Handle(e){
    props.values(e)
  }
  
  return(<div>
    <input type='text' onChange={Handle}></input>
  </div>)

}
```

//or:

```
function Nivedhan3(props){        // child comp 2
  
  return(<div>
    <input type='text' onChange={props.values}></input>
  </div>)

}
```